# Social Graph of common users of groups

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, social-networking, networkx

Trying to create Social graph using NetworkX in theory(as i think) everything is good works, but in practice works wrong.
So i've got information about some groups in such format:
members={'Group Name 1':[User 1 ID, User ID 2...],...,'Group Name N' : [User 1 ID,...,User K Id]}
For example:

```
members={'Group 1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
         'Group 2' : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 9], 
         'Group 3':[21,22,23,24] }
```

In outcome i need graph in which:

- Vertices - Social Group
- Edges - the existence of common subscribers (User IDs)
- Vertices Size - Users Count
- distance between Vertices - common Subscribers (User IDs)

My code:

```
matrix={}
for i in members:
    for j in members:
        if i!=j:
            matrix[i+j]=len(set(members[i]) & set(members[j]))*1.0/min(len(set(members[i])),len(set(members[j])))
max_matrix = max(matrix.values())
min_matrix = min(matrix.values())
for i in matrix:
    matrix[i] = (matrix[i] - min_matrix) / (max_matrix - min_matrix)

g = networkx.Graph(directed=False)
for i in members:
    for j in members:
        if i != j:
            g.add_edge(i, j, weight=matrix[i+j])

members_count = {x:len(members[x]) for x in members}

max_value = max(members_count.values()) * 1.0
size = []
max_size = 900
min_size = 100
for node in g.nodes():
    size.append(((members_count[node]/max_value)*max_size + min_size)*10)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pos=networkx.spring_layout(g)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
networkx.draw_networkx(g, pos, node_size=size, width=0.5, font_size=8)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

BUT, i can't understand why Edges drawing for groups which have no common IDs.

Comment: You should also look at bipartite projection as it performs a role much like what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkX only use weight as an attribute of edges. Whether there is an edge or not doesn't depend on edges' weights.

In other word, Those edges with weight 0 are also count as edges and it will be displayed by drawing function.